# Jackson Deserializer for one custom field?

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I believe we need a custom deserializer to do something specific with one field on our class.  It appears once I do this, I am now responsible for deserializing all the other fields.  Is there a way to have Jackson deserialize all the fields *except* the one I am concerned with here?

```
public class ThingDeseralizer extends StdDeserializer<Thing> {
    @Override
    public Thing deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(p);

        String special = node.get("special").asText();

        Thing thing = new Thing()
        thing.doSomethignWithSpecial(special)
        return thing;
    }
}
```

Thanx

Comment: Is object mutable?

Answer (score 19):

On your field in POJO add `@JsonDeserialize(using = ThingDeseralizer.class)` annotation.

This will tell Jackson how to deserialze that particular field, rest all will go as default.

Comment: Yes I just discovered this.  Hypothetically speaking is there a way to do this with a single deserializer on the class?  I imagine there has to be some method on the super class, or a different class to extend, that will fill out everything and let me override just what I want.

Comment: You mean to use deserializer on whole class? Than as you said you have to define all fields. But that's easy too, check this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson/7168386#7168386)

Comment: what's the relevant part in that link?

Comment: @hvgotcodes For serialization, `JsonSerializable` interface would do this, but unfortunately deserialization does not have similar support -- this is due to difficulties in defining suitable API: during serialization there is already an instance to call method on, but this is not the case for deserialization.

Comment: @hvgotcodes That custom ItemSerializer class to serialize the whole Item class. It's easy to serialize integer, string etc.